# Attaching listeners to nodes

Tags: neo4j

Is it possible to attach listeners to nodes? For instance if a property changed whoever is subscribed to the listener would get a notification? Or if a relationship changed on a node? Looking through the API there seems to be a Listener class in neo4j.helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at transaction event handlers: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/transactions-events.html

If that's what you're looking for then you could also check out the [GraphAware framework](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework/), specifically, [GraphAware Runtime Modules](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework/tree/master/runtime)

Disclaimer: I work for GraphAware

Comment: This looks like the best answer at this point in time. The Transaction Events return the transaction data for any given transaction to which you can piggyback off of for a notification type system.